# Optical Mark Recognition (OMR) on iPhone

Tags: objective-c, iphone, image-processing, omr

I'd like to be able to analyze an image captured with the iPhone camera and generate survey results (multiple choice). Apparently what I'm interested in is called OMR, Optical Mark Recognition (not OCR, Optical Character Recognition which is more sophisticated).

Does anyone know of any OMR libraries or source code that can be used to build such an iPhone app? And if not, any suggestions on rolling my own would be appreciated. Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is of interest to you:

http://cmgresearch.blogspot.com/2010/10/augmented-reality-on-iphone-with-ios40.html

It's from the developer of Sudoku Grab, which recognizes sudoku grids from the camera. It should definitely be useful to you.

Comment: He really only talks about how to grab raw camera images there.  His original writeup on how he did the recognition of shapes for Sudoku Grab is probably more relevant: http://sudokugrab.blogspot.com/2009/07/how-does-it-all-work.html

Comment: Those two have indeed been helpful (cmgresearch blog post and the sudoku one).  Thank you.  I'm hoping for some Objective-C source or a library that is along the lines of this article - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/showcase/SimpleOMRDotImage.aspx